# Error 403 forbidden error in localhost caused for htaccess

Tags: php, macos, apache

I wanted to develop in php + mySql with MacOX resources, not MAMP.

The problem arises when I use. Htaccess. I tried the same I use in MAMP, WAMP and production servers, which have never given problems so I think it must be a configuration error. 
Everything works fine until I include the htaccess. It throws a 403 Forbidden error and tells me I have no permissions. If I delete the htaccess everything works fine.

Any advice?

I followed this tutorial for installación.

http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-9-mavericks/

Thank you very much

---

Hi and thanks! I have partly solved!

My htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_URI} ^ / system. *
RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ Index.php? / $ 1 [L]
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}!-F
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}!-D
RewriteRule ^ (. +) $ Index.php? / $ 1 [L]
```

The solution was to comment the line #RewriteEngine On  and now throws the error.

I'm programming with CodeIgniter and I want to remove the index.

localhost / ~ user / project / contact does not work. 404 error

localhost / ~ user / project / index.php / contact if it works.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you include the contents of the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Thank you! I have indicated more data in the query

Answer (score 1):

in localhost, you have to delete it, 
while in the server side, put it again !

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short. Would you mind expanding it a little to explain how it solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using Mac OSX' buildin webserver functionality. In previous usages, I've noticed it has a non default configuration that makes it harder to debug.

As mentioned before the contents of the .htaccess file may be very relevant and posting them may help us solve the problem.

Also the permissions of the file could be relevant, al well as the httpd.conf file of apache (http://smartwebdeveloper.com/mac/httpd-conf-location-mac)

If .htaccess tries to load some kind of .htpasswd file (password authentication) this may explain the issue. If you move the .htacces but not the require .htpasswd file Apache is unable to authenticate.

You could probably get this to work but I would recommend a different development environment. Since most hosting is Linux based a (virtual) linux server may be a better solution. There are many tools out there that allows you to manage this without begin a sysadmin. Of course there nothing wrong with managing your development environment by hand.

If your're intersted in taking the effort os setting up a more advanced development environment I can recommend running Ubuntu Server in a VirtualBox (https://www.virtualbox.org/) instance. Even better may be create a development environment that is similar to the production environment.

I'm afraid you provided to little information to point out the problem but I would start with taking a look at the contents of the .htaccess file.

Comment: Thank you! I have indicated more data in the query.

Comment: Try to redo de rewriterules (http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/). Also try if an htaccess with just RewriteEngine On in it gives any problems...

Comment: A very interesting article. I'm going to study now! My knowledge on htacces is very basic... :(